# vim-clangを使用する際にfatal error: 'iostream' file not found と表示される

Tags: c++, vim

タイトルの通り、vim-clangを使用する際にfatal error: 'iostream' file not foundと表示され、補完が効きません。

[image: vim-clangのエラー画面]

自身の環境です。
ubuntu14.04.5 LTS
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0

neocompleteも使用しており、

/usr/bin/にはclangが以下のようにあります。

```
clang++-3.8                   clang-format-diff-3.4
clang-3.8                     clang-format-diff-3.6
clang-apply-replacements-3.8  clang-query-3.8
clang-check-3.8               clang-rename-3.8
clang-cl-3.8                  clear
clang-format-3.4              clear_console
clang-format-3.6
```

またプラグイン管理にはdein.vimを使用しており、
vim-clangの設定は以下のように記述しております。
(以下のページのコードを参考にさせていただきました。)

> http://qiita.com/koara-local/items/815b08ff5c6673d8a5c6

```
[[plugins]]
repo = 'justmao945/vim-clang'
hook_add = '''
" disable auto completion for vim-clang
let g:clang_auto = 0
let g:clang_complete_auto = 0
let g:clang_auto_select = 0
let g:clang_use_library = 1

" default 'longest' can not work with neocomplete
let g:clang_c_completeopt   = 'menuone'
let g:clang_cpp_completeopt = 'menuone'

" get clang path
function! s:get_latest_clang(search_path)
    let l:filelist = split(globpath(a:search_path, 'clang-*'), '\n')
    let l:clang_exec_list = []
    for l:file in l:filelist
        if l:file =~ '^.*clang-\d\.\d$'
            call add(l:clang_exec_list, l:file)
        endif
    endfor
    if len(l:clang_exec_list)
        return reverse(l:clang_exec_list)[0]
    else
        return 'clang'
    endif
endfunction

" get clang-format path
function! s:get_latest_clang_format(search_path)
    let l:filelist = split(globpath(a:search_path, 'clang-format-*'), 
'\n')
    let l:clang_exec_list = []
    for l:file in l:filelist
        if l:file =~ '^.*clang-format-\d\.\d$'
            call add(l:clang_exec_list, l:file)
        endif
    endfor
    if len(l:clang_exec_list)
        return reverse(l:clang_exec_list)[0]
    else
        return 'clang-format'
    endif
endfunction

let g:clang_exec = s:get_latest_clang('/usr/bin')
let g:clang_format_exec = s:get_latest_clang_format('/usr/bin')

" print debug
echo g:clang_exec
echo g:clang_format_exec

" compile options
let g:clang_c_options = '-std=c11'
let g:clang_cpp_options = '-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
'''
on_ft = ['c', 'cpp']
on_i = 1
```

この問題についてどなたかご教授いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージ通り`iostream`ファイルは存在するのでしょうか？ 存在しなければインストールの必要がありますし、存在しているのなら何らかのpath設定が適切でないことが予想されます。

Comment: `ls /usr/include/c++/4.8/ | grep iostream`で確認したところ確かに存在はします。 既に解決しましたが、libc++がインストールされていなかったみたいです。 ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

```
let g:clang_cpp_options = '-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
```

を

```
let g:clang_cpp_options = '-std=c++11'
```

に変えればいけるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: 下の設定に変えたところうまく動きました。ありがとうございます。  libc++が入ってなかったのですね。 libc++-devをインストールしたところ、元の設定でもうまく動きました。